# Computing inverse of matrix with very small precision values

Tags: matrices, inverse, numerical-linear-algebra

I have a square matrix with very small values of the order of 10^-9 or 10^-20. I need to compute the inverse of this matrix. But when I try to compute the inverse of the function using Python's inbuilt numpy.linalg.inv(.) function, I get an inverse matrix with all entries 0. Is there any transformation that can be applied to the matrix to extract the inverse approximation out of the original matrix.

Comment: Are **all** of the entries small (say, smaller than $10^{-9}$ in absolute value)?  If so, then Morgan's trick should work

Comment: Obligatory: Are you sure you need to compute the inverse? There might be more appropriate tools for the task you have in mind.

Comment: @Lorenzo Yes it is inverse itself. However, even if not exact, any approximations will also do.

Comment: This may help:https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/precision-handling-python/ and http://mpmath.org/ or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11522933/python-floating-point-arbitrary-precision-available